# ReflectionException, class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, reflection, namespaces, laravel-5

Giving the next code I'm getting this error when I try to post to *register*:

> ReflectionException in Route.php line 286: Class
>   App\Http\Requests\ApiRegisterRequest does not exist

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function() {
    Route::post('login', 'API\ApiController@authenticate');
    Route::post('register', 'API\ApiController@register');
});
```

**ApiController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function register(\App\Http\Requests\ApiRegisterRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

**ApiRegisterRequest**

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ApiRegisterRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required:min:3',
            'email' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        $messages = [
            'first_name.required' => 'Has de introducir un nombre'
            'email.required' => 'Has de introducir un correo'
        ];

        return $messages;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is Route.php code? In route section wrong segment, becouse in don't consist ApiRegisterRequest.

Comment: In your composer did you have a "psr-4" autoload, if not try to do `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
I did the dump-autoload before but didn't work

Comment: Maybe I've overlooked it, but if not, can you tell us where your line 268 is?

Answer (score 3):

The Error is caused because you have a syntax error in ApiRegisterRequest.

```
  $messages = [
        'first_name.required' => 'Has de introducir un nombre'
        'email.required' => 'Has de introducir un correo'
    ];
```

You have missed the colon at the end of the first entryo of $messages array.

Replace your messages by this:

```
    $messages = [
        'first_name.required' => 'Has de introducir un nombre',
        'email.required' => 'Has de introducir un correo'
    ];
```

This should do the trick